# Objectively, would it be better to sell my condo, or rent it out?

Tags: united-states, real-estate, real-estate-leasing

I bought a condo in 2016 for 160K, and this has been my primary residence since then. The loan was 152K, at 4.125% APR. I currently owe about 139K.

My mortgage is 898 (includes taxes and insurance in escrow), and my HoA is 560.

I’ve just purchased a new home, and was planning to sell the condo. However, it looks like the maximum I can get for it is between 145 and 150K, so more than I owe to the mortgage company, but less than I paid for it originally.

If I do rent it out, the best I can do is about 1200 a month, which would still have me paying about 2-300 a month out of pocket (898+560-1200), plus any taxes at the end of the year for the extra income.

Would it make more sense to rent it out and pay the extra OOP, or sell it for the lower price and just accept the loss in value?

Missing information (sorry!): I'm in the USA. There's no prepayment penalty. Current rates are lower, but all the fees associated with refinancing may not be a possibility.

Comment: What country are you in? Is a mortgage refinance possible? Are current available rates lower than your current rate? Does your current mortgage have prepayment penalties?

Comment: @yoozer8 sorry, added missing info.

Comment: A condo with a 560 HoA fee only rents for $1,200?

Comment: @DStanley unfortunately, yes. The condo is in the downtown area, and my HoA is higher because I have a downtown view + am on the 12th floor, but this side of downtown is mostly students and state/city government employees, which makes renting for higher much more difficult.

Comment: Then it's a horrible rental market. Or you have a condo that's not suitable for renting. Half of your rent eaten up by HoA dues is untenable. If the HoA fee is higher because of the view then the rent needs to be proportionally higher. If no one wants to pay for that benefit then it's not worth the cost.

Comment: I'm skeptical about your potential rent amount, very few markets are that unfavorable.

Comment: As the *correct* :)  answer below says very clearly, "Any real estate with a HoA payment sucks. For this reason, take it as a chance to dump it. Never again buy any real estate with a big HoA-type cost."  if the hoa costs are "incredibly high" relative to the situation, just dump it and write it off as a lesson.

Comment: @DStanley I guess I should add, this is the rent estimate I got out of Zillow, but not having any other sources to go to, that's the best I have. Thank you for your detailed answer, though! I really appreciate it.

Comment: @Fattie haha, fair enough. The one I've just bought definitely does not have HoA. I think your answer is great for for me a few years ago, but severely lacking in any detail for an objective answer for now.

Comment: @IsItMe - IMO: detail is bullshit coverage for positions with no rational basis.  the hoa on the deal you describe is *unbelievably* too high.  if it was "4.5% too high!" there could be a detail discussion on 1% either way. however, since it is *multiples* too high - dump it today.

Comment: @HartCO that's what I've seen online, and that's the best source of info I have. 2br/2b in 64106

Comment: @IsItMe It could just be a bummer of a rental, the accepted answer is simplified but probably the correct conclusion if the market isn't appreciating. You could likely make it more favorable with a refinance (I just got quotes sub 3% on investment loans). If you could get $1400/month it might change things but if you aren't particularly excited about being a landlord then probably not worth taking the chance. That HOA is a big bummer for sure if it doesn't include amenities that make it worth more as a rental.

Comment: Try looking at Craigslist or similar options to see what rentals are going for in your area.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

What you paid for it originally is of no financial consequence, just emotional. Your only reason to keep it from a value standpoint would be if you are pretty sure the value will go up in the future.

So let's look at it from an ROI standpoint:

At 4.125% APR, you're paying about $480 per month in interest and $260 in principal, so your net profit from renting it out would be 1,200 - (898-260) - 560 = $2 per month. That's a 0.24% capitalization rate on 10K of equity (2/10,000 * 12)

There's no real benefit to renting it out now at your current rates. You're spending all of the profit on interest, HoA fees (The HoA fee is effectively an additional 4% interest), and taxes/insurance. The 2-300 per month is just going to the equity in the condo, which you won't realize until you sell it anyways.

You'd be better off selling, keeping the 10K in equity, and paying down other debt, keeping it as an emergency fund, or investing it.

This would only start to make sense if you could rent it our for closer to 1,500 per month. That would make it a wash cash-flow-wise and would be closer to a 30% cap rate (which is only really 2% if you take into account the 15X leverage).

Even then, you still have the risk of having to cover the expenses if it goes unrented. A few months of sitting empty and you'll wipe out all of your equity in the property.

### EDIT:

From your comment:

> this is the rent estimate I got out of Zillow

Does Zillow know about the extra HoA fee for the magnificent view? Do they even include the HoA fee in their rent at all, or are you expected to tack it on? It's probably just looking at the square footage and comparing it to other units in the area (which probably varies quite a bit). If your property has idiosyncrasies that should be priced in then you should take that into consideration. I would increase the rent by at least the HoA fee. Then you're in realistic territory (financially anyways).

You could talk with a local property management firm to see what they would recommend you try to rent it for, but they may actually be a bit *high* to try and get your business (they get a % of the rental income in exchange for a lot of the mundane work).

Comment: Also, what amount of labor to you have to expend to earn that little?  Sell the condo.

Comment: IF, again that is specifically IF, the property, say, 7x in price in 20 years, every single figure mentioned in this post is, literally, so small it would hardly be calculable.  Yes, in terms of "as a rental" the property is comically bad and should be dumped this afternoon.

Comment: @Fattie 4% a year in interest and 4% a year in HoA dues is hardly insignificant. 7x in 20 years would be a massive 11% CAGR. Plus, this particular property has gone _down_ in value over the last 4 years. It sounds like an expensive (fee wise) condo in an area with low rent demand

Comment: In my experiences, Zillow's value estimates can be so wrong they're comical (there's lots of critical things they don't take into account). I second the recommendation to talk to a realtor, property management firm, or other human-type professional before making any decisions.

Comment: Original price *is* important for tax purposes. OP might want to look at what the optimal loss harvesting strategy is.

Comment: @DStanley thanks! So, if I could get about 1700, renting would make sense. I'm going to try to find a local property manager and see what they say.

Comment: @bta - will do, thanks! I was going to talk to the realtor who helped us buy the new place,  anyway, but figured I should have some knowledge instead of blindly following what they say

Comment: Well it would make _more_ sense. It's still not a great return given the amount of leverage (borrowed money) you use, but it's at least a viable option.

Answer (score -4):

(Con) Any real estate with a HoA payment ***sucks***.  For this reason, take it as a chance to dump it. Never again buy any real estate with a big HoA-type cost.

(Pro) In the 10-20 year time frame, real estate will usually drastically increase in nominal value, and since real estate is the *only* investment civilians enjoy leverage on, this is the very reason that you often hear folks say "Never sell anything" regarding real estate.  (The OOP is nothing and will disappear with inflation.)  In other words in 20 years (a) there is almost no chance you will lose money drastically on it (b) there is some chance you will make a massive, massive pile of money on it. For this reason, keep it and forget about it for 20 years.